# SOLR 6.6 OCR scanned PDF files

Tags: java, solr, ocr, tesseract

I have a pretty default (user guide) SOLR 6.6.0 installation on Linux working well.
Now I need to full-text (OCR) search also on scanned PDF files. I have read stuff about Tesseract with pictures. But I can't find a good tutorial how to implement this with PDFs.
Any suggestion on this?

Thanks,
Flo

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ExtractingRequestHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler).

Here You will find configuration examples, which could help You :

- http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/vijaym/using-solr-and-tikaocr-to-search-text-inside-an-image/
- https://fr.hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/indexing-and-searching-text-within-images-with-apache-solr/